Games get low frame rate and visual errors
I've noticed that when running doom 2 via GZDoom I get low fps and this green visual error visual bug  and I get a similar error on all source games (hl2, portal, TF2) I get low fps and visual errors visual bug #2 these issues don't happen on half life 1 so I'm confused
What is the cause of these issues and how do I fix them?


Some information about your computer and graphic card would be real helpful.

CPU is an Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU T5750 4 GB of RAM

This question is similar to: Gz doom giving fatal error. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

That's literally just my question I closed it because it was two questions in one post and I was told to close that question and open a new one. Perhaps read more carefully next time?

It sounds like your pc is not powerful enough to run these games. Especially Half-life 2, Portal, etc. I would expect needs a dedicated graphics card. I didn't think gzdoom was that demanding though. I have an old pc too, but it does have a graphics card.

That's the strange part, I can run hl2 at 20 ish fps but I still deal with graphics bugs. Since portal and TF2 run on the same engine I would think that they run like that too. I'm fine with not playing those but any idea on how to fix GZDoom?

Do you have mesa-utils installed? The screen shot you provided shows that your graphics driver is unknown. I don't think mesa-utils will actually fix anything, but after you install it, it should show you what graphics driver is installed, and I expect graphics driver issues are what you are having.

It says my graphics driver is Mesa Intel(R) 965GM (CL) 

Also, after reading on the forums, I discovered that TF2 is relies on the CPU way more than the GPU so it shouldn't matter too much I don't think...
